# How to test that NavigationService is configured?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm-light

Want the test to verify all navigation paths are as expected, so if someone changes the navigation path, the test will catch it.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void NavigationServiceIsConfigured()
    {
        NavigationService service = new NavigationService();

        // this is code under test put here for reference
        service.Configure("MainPage", typeof(MainPage));
        service.NavigateTo("MainPage");

        // Verify
        Assert.AreEqual("MainPage", service.CurrentPageKey);            
    }
```

However, it doesn't really test what I want to test.

Isn't there a way to access the dictionary that stores the string and type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went about it this way:

```
public class DefaultNavigationService : NavigationService
{
    public Dictionary<string, Type> Configuration
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }    
    public DefaultNavigationService() : base()
    {
        Configuration = new Dictionary<string, Type>();            
    }
    public new void Configure(string key, Type pageType)
    {
        Configuration.Add(key, pageType);
        base.Configure(key, pageType);
    }
}
```